# Name ImportError: cannot import name good_metaphases_list

Tags: python, python-import

This is the line of code where the error is occurring:

```
from combined import root, find_good_metaphases,good_metaphases_list, good_metaphases_list_with_coordinates, f2, make_gui_before, info_dialogue_box, red_cross, VerticalScrolledFrame
```

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Desktop\Chromosome\test_combining.py", line 9, in 
>   from combined import root, find_good_metaphases,good_metaphases_list, good_metaphases_list_with_coordinates, f2, make_gui_before, info_dialogue_box, red_cross, VerticalScrolledFrame
>       ImportError: cannot import name good_metaphases_list

Comment: please add the code which is throwing that beautiful traceback

Comment: also, reformat the traceback so we can actually read it

Comment: `combined` does not contain anything named `good_metaphases_list`.  Simple as that.

Comment: @JohnGordon it contains function find_good_metaphases through which I am trying to compute good_metaphase_list

Comment: If you need to _compute_ it, then why are you _importing_ it?

Comment: Also, is it spelled `good_metaphase_list` or `good_metaphases_list`?  Note the extra `s`.

Comment: @JohnGordon it is spelt as good_metaphases_list in my program.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have computed good_metaphases_list in combined.py and I want that result in test_combining.py for further processing and that's why I am importing it

Comment: Is it a variable inside of a function?  Variables inside functions can't be imported.

Comment: Have you gotten the hint that maybe you should _show us the code_?